# Does the WebSocket object abstract away frames?

Tags: javascript, websocket

The [WebSocket API object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) has an `onmessage` property and emits `message` events. However, there are no mentions of [frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.6). Is that because it is abstracted away?